# rails use enum to set up multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I want to know if I can use enum in rails 4.1 to set multiple roles to one user of it is only possible to have one role per user.  I added role to the user schema and then added the following to user.rb   I was also trying to set up a function so the first user created is admin and the rest are researcher but I'm not really sue what that would look like. Thanks!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
enum role: [:admin, :funder, :researcher]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :researcher
  end
```

Comment: You can create an admin user in your database seed script.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Hi, Thanks Aaron for answer, But what if I have [:salon_owner, beautician, visitor] roles and I need sometime to make some users to get salon_owner and beautician. and sometimes only beautician. how I may do that with enum?